# react-router-dom slug in location object empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Trying to add on my new page, path is "/review/:slug", other pages work correctly. But when im getting slug from useLocation hook it returns strange object without necessary params.

```
{
hash: ""
pathname: "/review/464052"
search: ""
state: undefined
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add the exact code instead of screenshots of the code. :)

Comment: You should use the ```useParams``` hook. Eg ```let { slug } = useParams();```